# How to refresh jqgrid using the response data returned from the edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am using the inlineNav edit options for Adding and Editing rows.  The data is being updated to the database correctly, but I can't find a way to refresh the grid after a successful save without posting back to the server.

All of the Questions & Answers that I find recommend doing 
    $.('grid').trigger('reloadGrid');

But that seems unnecessary if the response from the server already contains the required data.  It is primarily an issue when adding a new record and the ID value is displayed as jqg1.

I am using ASP.NET MVC4, with jqGrid 4.4.4.

Here is my view

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var emptyMsgDiv = $('<div>No school codes to display.</div>');
    var grid = $('#tblSchools');

    grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: 'json',
        viewrecords: true,
        url: '@Url.Action("SchoolsGridData")',
        editurl: '@Url.Action("EditSchoolsGridData")',
        colNames: ['School ID', 'Name', 'SACE Number', 'School Code', 'LEA Code', 'DFEE Code', 'Active'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'SchoolId', index: 'SchoolId', width: 80, key: true },
                    { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 190, editable: true },
                    { name: 'SaceSchoolNumber', index: 'SaceSchoolNumber', width: 105, editable: true, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'Code', index: 'Code', width: 105, editable: true, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'LeaCode', index: 'LeaCode', width: 80, editable: true, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'DfeeCode', index: 'DfeeCode', width: 80, editable: true, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'Active', index: 'Active', width: 80, editable: true, sortable: false }
        ],
        shrinkToFit: true,
        height: "100%",
        caption: 'School list',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 15, 20],
        emptyrecords: 'No school codes to display.',
        pager: '#schoolsPager',
        loadComplete: function () {
            var count = grid.getGridParam();
            var ts = grid[0];
            if (ts.p.reccount === 0) {
                grid.hide();
                emptyMsgDiv.show();
            } else {
                grid.show();
                emptyMsgDiv.hide();
            }
        }
    }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1 }]);

    emptyMsgDiv.insertAfter(grid.parent());

    grid.jqGrid('navGrid', "#schoolsPager", { edit: false, add: false, del: true });
    grid.jqGrid('inlineNav', '#schoolsPager', {
        addParams: {
            position: "last",
            addRowParams: {
                "keys": true,
                "aftersavefunc": function (rowid, response) {
                    alert('row: ' + rowid + ', response: ' + $.param(response));
                }
            }
        },
        editParams: {
            "aftersavefunc": function (rowid, response) {
                alert('row: '+rowid+', response: '+response);
            }
        }
    });

  });
</script>
<h3>Maintain Schools</h3>

<table id="tblSchools"></table>
<div id="schoolsPager" class="gridPager"></div>
```

and my Controller

```
public JsonResult EditSchoolsGridData(string oper, string SchoolId, string Name, string SaceSchoolNumber, string Code, string LeaCode, string DfeeCode, string Active)
{
  [Update Logic]

  return SchoolsGridData(string.Empty, "asc", 1, 10);
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult SchoolsGridData(string sidx, string sord, int? page, int? rows)
{
  [Get data logic]
}
```

I can see the response json being displayed in the aftersavefunc, but can't find a way to bind it to the grid.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the addRowData method which will set the data to grid with our reloading the grid

```
jQuery("#tblSchools").jqGrid('addRowData', response.SchoolId, response, "first");
```

[See the jqgrid methods wiki for more details](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods)

Comment: Thanks for that. I think the addRowData is more targeted at single rows, but right above it on the wiki was addJSONData. Pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: You are welcome. addJSONData is to add multiple rows and addRowData will add a single row. Then there is one more similar method setRowData which will replace the data with new one using the id of a  row.